# Powershell removing utf-8/ html formatting when combining files

Tags: html, powershell

This code is meant to combine 3 pieces of html the main is generated by ppowershell when the document is opened, it doesn't appear right and when opened in an html editor it doesn't  support / improper format it looks like this.

```
��<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Here is the code used to combine the files, the head and tails are html files

```
$main += $tile
$html = $head + $main + $tail
$html > .\Report.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out I used set content to enforce UTF8

```
$main += $tile
$html = $head + $main + $tail
$html | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path test2.html
```

Comment: Indeed: **`>` invariably creates UTF-16 LE-encoded files**. To use a different output encoding, as you've discovered, your must use `Out-File` (applies PS's default output formatting) or `Set-Content` (expects strings of just stringifies) with the `-Encoding` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$html | out-file "Report.html" -Encoding UTF8
```